# Print heart shape with words inside

Tags: c++, draw, cout, ascii-art

I am trying to draw a heart shape with words inside as a surprise for a friend tomorrow but i cant figure out how to put the words inside the heart . I am only able to draw the heart shape

Code to draw Heart

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x,y;
    double size=10;



    for (x=0;x<size;x++)
    {
        for (y=0;y<=4*size;y++)
        {
            double dist1 = sqrt( pow(x-size,2) + pow(y-size,2) );
            double dist2 = sqrt( pow(x-size,2) + pow(y-3*size,2) );

            if (dist1 < size + 0.5 || dist2 < size + 0.5 )
            cout<<"V";
            else
            cout<<" ";


        }
        cout<<endl;

    }

    for ( x=1;x<2*size;x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<x;y++)
        cout<<" ";

        for (y=0; y<4*size + 1 - 2*x; y++)
        cout<<"V";

        cout<<endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

**I need help putting words inside the heart shape**

Comment: Hint: the letters will be used instead of some of the spaces you output.

Comment: Why not just statically store the values in a char array, or do you want the message/size of the heart to be dynamic?

Comment: This may be a lot easier using a text editor rather than a program.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much the same as the other answer but I had already started so I thought I may as well finish. As a bonus you can specify what line of the "V" shape it prints on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x, y, size=10;
    string message(" hello there ");
    int print_line = 4;
    if (message.length() % 2 != 0) message += " ";

    for (x=0;x<size;x++) 
    {
        for (y=0;y<=4*size;y++)   
        {
            double dist1 = sqrt( pow(x-size,2) + pow(y-size,2) );
            double dist2 = sqrt( pow(x-size,2) + pow(y-3*size,2) );

            if (dist1 < size + 0.5 || dist2 < size + 0.5 ) {
                cout << "V";
            }
            else cout << " ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }

    for (x=1;x<2*size;x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<x;y++) cout << " ";

        for (y=0; y<4*size + 1 - 2*x; y++) 
        {            
            if (x >= print_line - 1 && x <= print_line + 1) {
                int idx = y - (4*size - 2*x - message.length()) / 2;
                if (idx < message.length() && idx >= 0) {
                    if (x == print_line) cout<<message[idx];
                    else cout << " ";
                }
                else cout << "V";
            }
            else cout << "V";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just wait until you get to a pre-specified position in the heart and print out a message instead of the "V"s, like this:

```
    char message[] = " MY MESSAGE ";
    for ( x=1;x<2*size;x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<x;y++)
        cout<<" ";

        for (y=0; y<4*size + 1 - 2*x; y++)
        {
            if (x == 1 && y == (2*size - strlen(message)/2))
            {
                cout << message;
                y += strlen(message)-1;
            }
            else
                cout<<"V";
        }

        cout<<endl;
    }
```

The `y += strlen(message)-1;` is to advance the column index according to the number of characters printed. `(2*size - strlen(message)/2)` is a position which will center the string.

If you want to obfuscate the code as much as possible (so you don't know what the message is until the code runs), you could use a hash table to map positions to letters or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>    
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout<<"Print Heart....C++\n";

        int n=7; //size of heart
        for(int i=-3*n/2;i<=n;i++){
            for(int j=-3*n/2;j<=3*n/2;j++){
    /* inside either diamond or two circles */
            if((abs(i)+abs(j)<n)||((-n/2-i)*(-n/2-i)+(n/2-j)*(n/2-j)<=n*n/2)||((-n/2-i)*(-n/2-i)+(-n/2-j)*(-n/2-j)<=n*n/2)){
                   cout<<"v ";
               }
               else{
                   cout<<"  ";
               }
            }
               cout<<"\n";
        }
        cout<<"\n\n\nPlease don\'t forget to like.... :) :) :) \n";
        cout<<"Credit: Heart Of Java : https://code.sololearn.com/caiu85u6tr30/#java";
    return 0;
}
```

Demo here: https://code.sololearn.com/cuXe0axsK8R2/#cpp

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for answer. Please review to improve your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer